# PHP, splitting strings by n characters

Tags: php

I'm making my website and I have never come across what is happening here. I am getting all articles from the database and echoing each articles title and a brief 12 characters of the content, this forms a list of the articles to choose from. However, when I use the substr method it doesn't do it correctly.

```
<?php
                $get_articles = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `articles` ORDER BY `ID` DESC");
                while($article = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_articles)){
                    $articleID = $article['ID'];
                    $articleTitle = $article['Title'];
                    $articleText = $article['Text'];
                    $articleDate = $article['Date'];

                    $sText = substr($articleText, 0, 12);
                    echo "$sText";
                }
            ?>
```

this should echo out from my text 'Ahh, Christm' but instead, it give this output 'Ahh, ChristmSeeing if th' which is the first 12 characters and 12 characters from near the end of the article. Help please.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the first 12 characters of the next entry?

Comment: Yes you are right just like PiotrK. Thanks both of you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is echoing `$sText` for every loop pass without any delimeter, so what you probably see is substr of first `Text` field followed by immediately second `Text` from the second row in your database

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to add break tags after the echo to separate them. One of the stupidest mistakes I have ever made. You'll receive the answer once the 8 minutes runs out.

Comment: @HarrisonPickering Not a problem, we all have done something like that at least once in our career :D